# Max $Z=4x_1+5x_2$ Using two phase simplex

Tags: optimization

> max $$z=4x_1+5x_2$$
>   s.t $$3x_1+x_2\leq27$$
>   $$x_1+x_2=12$$
>   $$3x_1+2x_2\geq 30$$
>   $$x_1,x_2\geq 0$$

To start the process we find an initial solution, so we add a slack variables:

$$3x_1+x_2+x_3 = 27$$
$$x_1+x_2+x_4=12$$
$$3x_1+2x_2-x_5= 30$$
$$x_1,x_2, x_3,x_4,x_5\geq 0$$

or should it be

$$3x_1+x_2+x_3 = 27$$
$$x_1+x_2+x_4=12$$
$$3x_1+2x_2-x_5+x_6= 30$$
$$x_1,x_2, x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6\geq 0$$

Comment: I have got $$x_1=x_2=6$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To set up an LP in augmented form, to prepare it for either the two-phase method or the big-$M$, method:

- Each $\le$ constraint gets a slack variable
- Each $=$ constraint gets an artificial variable
- Each $\ge$ constraint gets both a surplus variable and an artificial variable

So, *your second set of constraints is correct*.

- $x_3$ is a slack variable
- $x_4$ is an artificial variable
- $x_5$ is a surplus variable and $x_6$ is an artificial variable.